# Im trying to create a function within an object that calls and uses another function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, object

Im writing algorithms for a scrabble scoring program in javascript Node JS, and im trying to use create an object that has a function as a value. That function calls and uses another function, but for whatever reason it says my function is not defined.

I have tried searching google for a solution with no luck.

```js
//this is the original score key

const oldScoreKey = {
  1: ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'L', 'N', 'R', 'S', 'T'],
  2: ['D', 'G'],
  3: ['B', 'C', 'M', 'P'],
  4: ['F', 'H', 'V', 'W', 'Y'],
  5: ['K'],
  8: ['J', 'X'],
  10: ['Q', 'Z']
};

//below is a transform function that reverses the keys and values of oldScoreKey

function transform(obj) {
  const newScoreKey = {};
  for (var key in oldScoreKey) {
    for (let i = 0; i < oldScoreKey[key].length; i++) {
      newScoreKey[oldScoreKey[key][i].toLowerCase()] = +key;
    }
  }
  return newScoreKey;
}

let newScoreKey = transform(oldScoreKey);

//below is the new object that has the scoreFunction key that is causing the problem.

let scrabbleScoring = {
  name: 'Scrabble',
  description: 'The traditional scoring algorithm.',
  scoreFunction: function(word) {
    var letter, i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      letter = word[i];
      sum += newScoreKey[letter];
    }
  }
};

console.log(scrabbleScoring.scoreFunction('word'))
```

The expected result is for whatever word is entered into `scoreFunction`, 
to be scored according to the point system layed out by `newScoreKey`. 
But i get an error stating that `newScoreKey` is undefined when I try to call `scoreFunction`.

Comment: Typo: `let newScorekey` should be `let newScoreKey`

Comment: misspelled the score thing in second sub function in obj

Comment: Also, `scoreFunction()` should end with `return sum`.

Comment: @dezratt That's a different question...

Comment: Im super new to stack, is there a way to mark this as officially answered now?